# React animation when removing an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am quite new to React. I am trying to learn by implementing a full CRUD. However, I am unable to get animation working well for removing a course from the list.

I have configured animation on `transitionAppear` and on `transitionLeave`.
The `transitionAppear` works alright. I can't get the `transitionLeave`

This is my component:
https://github.com/leonardoanalista/react-crud/blob/master/src/components/course/CourseListRow.js

This is the CSS for the animation:
https://github.com/leonardoanalista/react-crud/blob/master/src/style.css#L66

Please let me know if there is a better approach.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

cheers
Leonardo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have ReactCSSTransitionGroup being rendered along with the group which is something you shouldn't be doing per [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#animation-group-must-be-mounted-to-work) because the group needs to be mounted inside of the transition group. I understand that you want to do the transition on each row but for this to work it needs to be on a the tbody.

All what you need to do is take out `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` from CourseListRow component and add it to CourseList:

```
</thead>
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName="course-item"
  transitionLeave={true}
  transitionAppear={true}
  transitionAppearTimeout={2500}
  transitionEnterTimeout={1700}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}
  component="tbody"
>
  {this.props.courses.map(course =>
    <CourseListRow key={course.id} course={course} removeCourse={this.props.removeCourse} />
  )}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
</table>
```

I made a pull request on your repo with the bug fixed.

Comment: Thank you Hussein! I thing I tried this approach but I didn't go up to the `thead`. `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` animations are really impressive. I copied the 2 files you changed manually to new commit: https://github.com/leonardoanalista/react-crud/commit/1e81d7b8f70f64f173b4c34391d0f38f64258519

Comment: Sure! Can you accept the answer as the correct one?